# Confused about the behavior of regex in a url routing script

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I just finished learning about regex and I thought that I should put it into something useful, so I created a small url routing script with php and the following regex:

```
^(?:/(\w+)?)*$
```

(the php code currently doesnt do anything, just prints out the matching groups from preg_match)
currently if given the url `/foobar/foo/bar`, the matching groups are the entire string (normal behavior) and the last part of the url (in this case: `bar`).
Obviously, this is a problem.

I think that this is caused because of the use of 1 capture group, which only captures the last matching string, but I'm not sure. any advice on the real cause of this and/or a solution to this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Come again, what exactly is the problem? What do you want to capture? Your regex looks rather risky with the nested "yes, but, no, but" repetition operators (it's the Vicky Pollard regex!) but without more information about what you want to match, it's not clear how to improve it, either.

Comment: @tripleee I was hoping that each group will be remembered on its own, and not overwritten on each match (but that's impossible according to the answer Tim gave). The regex is so 'risky' because I wanted to just be able to throw a url at him without any checks in the code before, so I made the regex do what's the code would do otherwise (stripping slashes, matching an empty path, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have diagnosed the problem correctly - on each repetition of the surrounding group, the previously matched contents of the capturing group are "overwritten" by the new match.

It's not quite clear what you would have expected to happen. I guess that you would have liked each part of the path to be "remembered" as its own group? This is something you can't do with repeated groups in PHP (only a few regex dialects (Perl 6 and .NET) allow something like this).

In your case, you're probably better off by using your regex to validate the URL and then split it along the slashes:

```
$result = preg_split('%/%', $subject);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought would happen (maybe it's time to switch back to perl? :P). About your suggestion, wouldn't it be better to use `explode` instead of `preg_split` (from a performance point of view)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be (since you're splitting on a fixed character).

Comment: It turns out there is a way to accomplish that in php - I modified the regex so it wouldn't include the the '*' and used `preg_match_all` which gives me all the parts.